# How do I make my code discern how to divide my array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have to read this line from the text file:

Asta Ieva 5 0 17 10 23 23

The first two words are a name, all the others are different numbers. How do I make it so that that my program creates a list that goes like this: (name, number, number, number...)

Comment: There are some things to clarify in your question. You mention reading from a file - is reading the file part of your problem, or could your question be asked the same if the input was just a string? Is the name always two words long? What have you tried already? Did you do some research? Splitting a string is quite a basic task with alot of information online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using `line.split(" ")` to break up the individual words. Then you can use `str.isdigit()` to test which are names and which are numbers.

For example:

```
mylist = ["Number" if word.isdigit() else "Name" 
          for word in line.split(" ")]
```

If you need to split the array into names and numbers you could do something like

```
words = line.split(" ")
numbers = []
names = []
for word in words:
    if word.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(word))
    else:
        names.append(word)
```